# Treating a rotating rod like a point mass at the cm

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, rotation

If I were to have a uniform rod that is rotating about one of its ends, am I able to treat the center of mass of the rod as a point mass and have the point mass rotate around the end?

Image:
[image]

My thinking: When I try and solve for quantities such as the tangential velocity or centripetal acceleration when the rod/point mass is vertical, I get different values.

Rod: By energy conservation, I get that $mg(L/2)=1/2*Iω^2$ and solving for ω treating $ I = ml^2/3$, I get $ω=(3g/l)$<sup>1/2</sup>, thus the tangential velocity for the center of mass would be $v=rω=(3gl/4)$<sup>1/2</sup>.
Looking at the case of the point mass, I have $mg(L/2) = 1/2*mv^2$ which leads to a tangential velocity of $v=(gl)$<sup>1/2</sup>

The question: Assuming my calculations are correct (please correct me if I'm wrong or have misunderstood my own ideas), why am I not able to approximate the rod as a point mass at the center of mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never treat a rotating object as a point located at its center of mass, because this always changes the moment of inertia. The moment of inertia of a point mass located at the center of mass is $mR_{cm}^2$, while by the parallel axis theorem the original moment of inertia is $I_0+mR_{cm}^2$, where $I_0$ is the moment of inertia of the rod about the center of mass.

A point mass is simply different than an extended object. With the motion of an extended object, some of the energy goes into the rotation of the object around its center of mass instead of into the rotation of the center of mass around the origin.